# Convert jQuery to JS toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to convert the following jQuery code into vanilla JavaScript and I'm having some trouble. Below is the jQuery code:

Following jQuery code:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('.navbar-burger').on('click',function() {
            $('.navbar-burger').toggleClass('is-active');
            $('.navbar-menu').toggleClass('is-active');
        });

    });

} )( jQuery );
```

Here is my JS attempt:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-burger').onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('is-active');
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements you need to loop through and set the event on each manually. jQuery's `on` is internally doing this loop

Comment: is there many element with class `.navbar-burger` , `.navbar-burger`, `.navbar-menu`  ?  (better to show html paart of this) translate jQuery code to JS may be use a diffrent way to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `addEventListener` JS function with `click`. Use querySelector method to toggle the class on `menu` and `nav` in Pure JS.

Using `document.getElementsByClassName` will **not** work as you tried because it returns the list of elements you will need foreach loop for that. In you case it not required.

**Edit:** Also, I see you are using jQuery `$(document).ready` in pure JS you can use `DOMContentLoaded` - this will make sure your `script` is ready when page loads.

**Demo**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  //Nav burger
  let navBurg = document.querySelector('.navbar-burger')

  //Nav menu
  let navMenu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu')

  //Click function
  navBurg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('is-active');
    navMenu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-burger">
  Click Me
 
</button>

<div class="navbar-menu">
  Menu
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution only works for 1 item. If he had menu accessible from more than 1 element your code does not work.

Comment: Am just commenting the difference; more than 1 way to skin a cat. Often people don't specify their requirement down to the T; so at least OP can see difference between these two solutions.

Comment: Settle down. These two solutions are enough. I'm not mocking your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to change.

1. Replace `$(document).ready` with the `DOMContentLoaded` event or place the script before the closing `</body>` tag.
2. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements matching a selector instead of `$`. You will need to loop over all the elements manually.
3. Use `Element.addEventListener(eventName,handler)` instead of `$(...).on(eventName, handler)`.
4. Use `Element.classList.toggle` instead of `$(...).toggleClass`.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   const burgers = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger');
   const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-menu');
   burgers.forEach(burger => burger.addEventListener("click", function(){
        burgers.forEach(burger => burger.classList.toggle('is-active'));
        menus.forEach(menu => menu.classList.toggle('is-active'));
   }));
});
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket to close initial ``burgers.forEach(``

Comment: @Dexterians Thanks for telling me.